# Does " whether nothing can be done to solve crime problems is debatable." sounds odd to you

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions, sentence-usage, ielts

I'm writing an IELTS practice essay now.

In the example essay, there is a transition sentence saying "Nevertheless, whether nothing can be done to solve crime problems is debatable. " I know it is grammatically correct, but it still sounds a little bit odd to me.

What do you think? And how would you write it?

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a good formal sentence after preceding material has put forward the idea that crime problems can't be solved.

You could change the word order:
"Still, it's debatable whether nothing can be done to solve crime problems."

You could split it up:
"The foregoing suggests that nothing can be done about the problems resulting from crime. But that is debatable."

You could cut out some negation:
"It's debatable whether anything can be done to solve crime problems."
but that may change the emphasis.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your advice.